# How to edit the sudoers file when it has nothing and has no permission?

Tags: linux, sudoers

I login with non-root user, e.g. jason, and can not edit the /etc/sudoers file.
After type "ls -la /etc/sudoers", it shows following:

```
-r--r----- 1 root root 792 Jan  6 06:31 /etc/sudoers
```

And type "vi /etc/sudoers", the file shows nothing, it is empty.
However I have no permission to edit it, and also cannot become a root user.

How to edit the sudoers file to edit the "jason" user?

Comment: You need to be a privileged user in order to edit the sudoers file. So you can become root and add the user.

Comment: Hi @kometen, I can not become root user.

Comment: If this server is managed by another person you must then get in touch with that person.

Comment: This question belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic security feature.

If you don't have root permissions (sudo), you should not be able to edit the sudoers file (if not you wil just give yourself permissions)

**note**: never edit directly the sudoers file, but use the command `visudo`. This will validate the file before saving it, preventing to save a corrupt file and 'locking yourself out'

Answer (score 0):

That does not work if you do not have administrative privileges, in
Ubuntu 20.04: log in and find settings.
Settings
Users
click add user (authenticate to unlock settings)
You have to add another user and make them an administrator.
Or click the account in question, and turn on the administrator switch.
Requires a logout after the change. Now sudo will work after authentication.